# Vagrant up command not working

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

When I do `vagrant up` command, I get the following error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/root/.vagrant.d/boxes/coreos-beta/557.2.0/virtualbox/box.ovf"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /root/.vagrant.d/boxes/coreos-beta/557.2.0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium storage unit '/root/.vagrant.d/boxes/coreos-beta/557.2.0/virtualbox/coreos_production_vagrant_image.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: inconsistent references to grain directory in '/root/.vagrant.d/boxes/coreos-beta/557.2.0/virtualbox/coreos_production_vagrant_image.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file '/root/.vagrant.d/boxes/coreos-beta/557.2.0/virtualbox/coreos_production_vagrant_image.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance, callee 
Context: "ImportAppliance" at line 793 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to resolve this by removing Virtualbox and installing the newest version from the VB website.